# Update Text Unity 4.6 UI Element

Tags: javascript, c#, unity-game-engine

I'm developing a small "Hello World" web app using Unity3D and I need to update a *Text* element (I'm using the brand new UI elements added in the latest unity release, 4.6).
I've been following several tutorials, including the Unity's official docs, and it doesn't work.
Here I post some code:

First of all my C# script, as you can see, i'm setting the initial value of the variable named "name" to "Unknown",
the goal is update it using the input name.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class ChangeText : MonoBehaviour {

    Text text;
    string name;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        text = GetComponent<Text>(); 
        name = "Unknown";

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        text.text ="Welcome " + name;
    }

    void updateLabelText(string inputName) {
        Debug.Log ("input >> " + name);
        name = inputName;
   }
}
```

Here the website side javascript code:

```
function SaySomethingToUnity() {
    input = document.getElementById('inputName').value;
    u.getUnity().SendMessage("text", "updateLabelText", input);
    //alert(input);
}
```

And finally the HTML to write user's name:

```
<div>
    <input type="text" name="enter" class="enter" value="" id="inputName"/>
    <input type="button" value="click" onclick="SaySomethingToUnity();"/>
</div>
```

If anyone can help me...

Thank all for wasting your time in my post!! :D

Comment: within the line `u.getUnity().SendMessage("text", "updateLabelText", input);` isn't the class isn't the object meant to be `ChangeText` not `text`?  if that's not it, could you expound a little on "it doesn't work"?

Comment: @Lefty thank you for your time!! Based in your reply I realized that the first parameter refers to the name of the object which recive the update. Again... thank you so much!!